# What's the proper way to create a case-loop/switch-statement-type PowerShell function?

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

Because of the possibility that I'm really stuck on an X-Y problem here, what I'm actually doing is writing a rather large script to handle user administration for on-prem and cloud-based users on a Windows platform. This means a handful of on-prem services, authenticated using Active Directory credentials, and a handful of cloud-based services, using Azure Active Directory credentials.  Ideally, there would be one set of credentials that could perform all the actions, but I can't rely on that, which leaves me looking for a way to get a number of credentials (I'm up to about 8) that will then be sent on to the appropriate `Connect-[Service]` function I've written.

I think the proper way to write this function is with a switch statement, along the lines of:

```
Function Get-Credentials {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Service
    )

    $global:Service1Credentials = $null;
    $global:Service2Credentials = $null;
    ...

    switch ($Service)
    {
        Service1 { $global:Service1Credentials = Get-Credential  -Message "Credentials for [Service1]"}
        Service2 { $global:Service2Credentials = Get-Credential  -Message "Credentials for [Service2]"}
        ...
    }
}
```

Ignoring the use of global parameters (which I'm doing for better debugability while I write the script), is this the proper approach to the problem of getting credentials for a script to use against several to a dozen different services, or is there a better approach I should be using?

Comment: There certainly isn't anything wrong with that and I can't think of anything better.

Comment: @EBGreen Damn.  I was hoping for different answer, honestly.  It looks so gross and inelegant with 8 services (and counting) in there.

Comment: Well, really, if the function simply returns credentials you could just use a generic message like "Enter credentials for " + $service . Then return the credentials.

Comment: If the function isn't using the credentials it doesn't need to know what they are for anyway.

Comment: I'd suggest using a `[ValidateSet()]` on the `$Service`

Comment: Also `}` acts as an implicit break on the switch so items won't fall through.

Comment: Personally I would only bother with that if the function uses the credentials. If it just asks the user for credentials and returns the credential object it shouldn't need to know if the service name is in a validation list or not.

Comment: @EBGreen This is true, but I think I get some benefit out of breaking them out into different variables, so I can try, for example using the Azure AD credentials against Sharepoint online and only prompt again if none of the already provided credentials work.  That becomes less useful if a single generic credential variable gets overwritten each time the function is called.  I think.  I’m open to being wrong about that, though.

Comment: So, where you call the function assign the returned object to whatever variable you want. I'm just saying that it doesn't sound like the function needs to have different variables. Even if you are using the credential in the function, it has the service name. So in the function it only needs one variable for the credential. Another way to say it is that no matter which service you give the function there will only ever be one credential object in the function so the name of the variable holding it is irrelevant.

Comment: The reason I would avoid the switch statement (and a ValidateSet) for that matter is that it more tightly couples the code to the code outside the function. For instance in a year when this code has already been in production for 11 months if you want to add a service you would have to remember to come change this code. If the function is service agnostic though you would have fewer places to change it.

Comment: @EBGreen Oh, yes.  That would be a significant improvement.  X-Y problem after all.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative that will be a little less cumbersome as the switch options grow:

```
function Get-SvcCred($ServiceName)
{
    return (Get-Credential  -Message "Credentials for $ServiceName")
}

$services = "Service1", "Service2", "Service3"

$creds = @{}

$services | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $creds[$_] = Get-SvcCred $_
    }
```

Now, all you have to do is update the $services array as new ones are added and this will correctly ask for each one in turn.  The added benefit is that you can easily access any set of credentials later in the code by doing something like this:

```
$creds["Service1"]
```

Obviously, if you don't want (or need) the user to give all the credentials at once, you can simply make each call as and when required:

```
$creds["Service3"] = Get-SvcCred "Service3"
```

Comment: Of course if that is all that the function does then I would question the need for the function in the first place. :)

Comment: @EBGreen, agreed.  A nice bit of tunnel vision I think - question asked for a function, so I wrote one (such as it is) without wondering if it was necessary :-(.